# How to fix the PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING in C

Tags: c, pcap

I have an application using pcap. The linker as got the correct libs and the include path. (In Code::Blocks/Build Options: I did it for both Release and Debug) I have no errors to compile the program with the pcap header. So, everything seems fine. BUT, If I want to determine the device list for available adapters I have to use them

```
//...
pcap_if_t alldevices;
pcap_findalldevs(PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING, NULL, &alldevices, error_buffer); //This function.
```

function. The compiler throws following error: `'PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING'` was not declared in this scope. By the way, I'm using windows if that matters.
So my question: Is there any other pcap header file with I have to include? Or another definition which must be included? I wonder why only this thing isn't working. Everything else does.

Comment: have you included `pcap.h` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
#define HAVE_REMOTE
```

then `include pcap.h`

and cast `"PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING"`to `char*`

Example:

```
if (pcap_findalldevs_ex((char*)PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING, NULL, &alldevs, errbuf) == -1)
```